# Titanic training

Tags: python, scikit-learn

so I am testing to see which machine learning models perform the best when it comes to accuracy but it is telling me that my dataset is too large:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-534e381534e9> in <module>()
----> 1 models(x_train, y_train)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype)
    114             raise ValueError(
    115                 msg_err.format(
--> 116                     type_err, msg_dtype if msg_dtype is not None else X.dtype
    117                 )
    118             )

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Here is the github link to the code review over it:

https://github.com/tquigg96/TitanicSurvivalPredictions.git

if anyone has any idea on how to fix this that would be uber helpful. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You may already know this, but [Titanic](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic) is a hugely popular topic on Kaggle. You'll find a lot of example notebooks there.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will take a look at those.

Answer (score 1):

The sklearn implementation of logistic regression does not handle NaN (not a number) -> missing values. This means that you must first address the missing values either by imputing or removing the rows with missing values.

Comment: oh that makes sense